# auto upgrade for dissimilar products in a single click

Tags: c#, deployment, setup-deployment

I have four dissimilar products. They are:

1. Outlook add-on product
2. System-Tray product
3. Standard EXE product
4. IE add-on product

Those products are developed in C# .NET. Those products are given as a single product to the client. I want to upgrade automatically all those products in a single click. (i.e. all the products must be upgraded to new version in a single click).  The upgrade must be a compulsory update (i.e. it would not allow the client to run the product until he get the upgrade).

Can anybody guide me over this problem?

Comment: Remind me not to buy your products, please.

Comment: What are you using for the setup packages (e.g. Visual Studio setup project, ClickOnce, WIX, 3rd-party MSI packager...)?

Comment: @ewall: i am using visual studio setup project

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: why your are saying this, what did you mean regarding this

Comment: I don't mind being advised to upgrade; I do mind not being allowed to use my software because I have not upgraded.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler : this is pretty common for client-server applications. BTW, it happens to you every single time you use a Web application :)

Comment: @Brann: with the web application, I'm not asked to do the upgrade with a click.  If you are going to do the upgrade, do it seamlessly and without bothering me.  As Chrome does, for example.

Answer (score 1):

1. Put all your code - forms and all - into one or more dlls.
2. On startup - or whenever you want if you're up for the challenge - the exes will check for updates to those dlls based on the last UpdateID / dll version in a webservice call.
3. If there is an updated version, download it and overwrite the old dll.
4. Dynamically load and consume the update-able dlls with Reflection.
5. Consider using a mutex to avoid duplication of update efforts.  Name the mutex after the UpdateID.

This could be finessed to allow in-flight updating.

Comment: Just to add: The code does not have to be in separate DLLs. For Example, I've got 6 `Projects` under 1 `Solution` in `Visual Studio`. When I build my application, all 6 `Projects` are compiles (they also share many of the same class files to enable the `Projects` all work the same). This produces a single executable that installs on the User's PC.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)